# MongoDB $pull from array of objects and from multiple objects arrays inside array in single .updateOne()

Tags: mongodb

I have a library document, which looks like:

```
library: {
  '_id': ObjectId("58380bd7ae1d7b1278dbb79f"),
  'shelves': [
    { 
      'type': 'sci-fi',
      'bookshelf': 1,
      'books': [ ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2ce"), ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2d1")]
    }
  ],
  'books': [
     {
       '_id': ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2ce"),
       'title': 'Lorem',
       'author': 'Foo Bar',
     },
     {
       '_id': ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2d1"),
       'title': 'Ipsum',
       'author': 'Dolor Sit',
     }
  ]
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to `$pull` single book from `library.books` and from each of the `library.shelves.books` which contains it in single `updateOne()` (or any other method) call without restructuring? Assume that there will be a lot of shelves and one book can be on many of them.

Right now I am doing it in two separate calls, so wondering if it can be done more efficiently.

**EDIT:**

Let's say I want first book from the example above `$pull`ed. Then, my library would look like:

```
library: {
  '_id': ObjectId("58380bd7ae1d7b1278dbb79f"),
  'shelves': [
    { 
      'type': 'sci-fi',
      'bookshelf': 1,
      'books': [ ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2d1")]
    }
  ],
  'books': [
     {
       '_id': ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2d1"),
       'title': 'Ipsum',
       'author': 'Dolor Sit',
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just couple up the 2 `$pull`s in one update, one for pulling the item from the shelve and one for pulling it from the books:

```
> db.library.update({"shelves.books" : ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2ce")},
...     {
...         $pull: {
...             "shelves.$.books" : { $in : [ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2ce")] },
...             "books" : { "_id" : ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2ce")}
...         }
...     })
```

Will return

```
> db.library.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58380bd7ae1d7b1278dbb79f"),
        "shelves" : [
                {
                        "type" : "sci-fi",
                        "bookshelf" : 1,
                        "books" : [
                                ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2d1")
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "books" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("583817c043bf901f2c8ff2d1"),
                        "title" : "Ipsum",
                        "author" : "Dolor Sit"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Comment: Check my edit, you misunderstood, as far as I can see from provided example of returned data. I don't want whole shelve to be gone, just the book from it.

Comment: Sorry my bad, example made it a lot easier to work with. I've updated the update query to reflect your example. This now uses the `position` operator which come from the update query.